# Issues with a button not working when SQL is being used to get data from a table

Tags: c#, sql, desktop-application

This is some code I got off the internet because I'm quite new to SQL and had no intentions of using it until I came across this login feature I wanted to add into my desktop application. Here's the code.

```
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=JOASH;Initial Catalog=Logins;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login WHERE Username='" + flatTextBox1.Text + "' AND Password='" + flatTextBox2 + "'", connection);
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        if (dataTable.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {
            this.Hide();
            Dashboard dashboard_form = new Dashboard();
            dashboard_form.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Authentication failed!");
        }
```

That is the part where the SQL stuff is taking place for the Button. Basically, on clicking a button, the code is executed. But, for some reason, when I click the button, either the code isn't executing, or it isn't working. (I'm guessing it isn't executing.) I really hope that someone can help me with this. The button just won't work.

EDIT: As requested by Nirman, here's the Form Designer code.

```
    namespace subTerraApplication
    {
partial class WelcomePage
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.formSkin1 = new FlatUI.FormSkin();
        this.flatTextBox2 = new FlatUI.FlatTextBox();
        this.flatLabel2 = new FlatUI.FlatLabel();
        this.flatTextBox1 = new FlatUI.FlatTextBox();
        this.flatLabel1 = new FlatUI.FlatLabel();
        this.flatMini1 = new FlatUI.FlatMini();
        this.flatMax1 = new FlatUI.FlatMax();
        this.flatClose1 = new FlatUI.FlatClose();
        this.flatButton1 = new FlatUI.FlatButton();
        this.formSkin1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // formSkin1
        // 
        this.formSkin1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.formSkin1.BaseColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(60)))), ((int)(((byte)(70)))), ((int)(((byte)(73)))));
        this.formSkin1.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(53)))), ((int)(((byte)(58)))), ((int)(((byte)(60)))));
        this.formSkin1.Controls.Add(this.flatButton1);
        this.formSkin1.Controls.Add(this.flatTextBox2);
        this.formSkin1.Controls.Add(this.flatLabel2);
        this.formSkin1.Controls.Add(this.flatTextBox1);
        this.formSkin1.Controls.Add(this.flatLabel1);
        this.formSkin1.Controls.Add(this.flatMini1);
        this.formSkin1.Controls.Add(this.flatMax1);
        this.formSkin1.Controls.Add(this.flatClose1);
        this.formSkin1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.formSkin1.FlatColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(52)))), ((int)(((byte)(152)))), ((int)(((byte)(219)))));
        this.formSkin1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 12F);
        this.formSkin1.HeaderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(45)))), ((int)(((byte)(47)))), ((int)(((byte)(49)))));
        this.formSkin1.HeaderMaximize = false;
        this.formSkin1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.formSkin1.Name = "formSkin1";
        this.formSkin1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(256, 349);
        this.formSkin1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.formSkin1.Text = "subTerra Build 1";
        // 
        // flatTextBox2
        // 
        this.flatTextBox2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.flatTextBox2.FocusOnHover = false;
        this.flatTextBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(125, 135);
        this.flatTextBox2.MaxLength = 32767;
        this.flatTextBox2.Multiline = false;
        this.flatTextBox2.Name = "flatTextBox2";
        this.flatTextBox2.ReadOnly = false;
        this.flatTextBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(109, 29);
        this.flatTextBox2.TabIndex = 10;
        this.flatTextBox2.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        this.flatTextBox2.TextColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(192)))), ((int)(((byte)(192)))), ((int)(((byte)(192)))));
        this.flatTextBox2.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
        // 
        // flatLabel2
        // 
        this.flatLabel2.AutoSize = true;
        this.flatLabel2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.flatLabel2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 15.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.flatLabel2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.flatLabel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 135);
        this.flatLabel2.Name = "flatLabel2";
        this.flatLabel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(99, 30);
        this.flatLabel2.TabIndex = 9;
        this.flatLabel2.Text = "Password";
        // 
        // flatTextBox1
        // 
        this.flatTextBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.flatTextBox1.FocusOnHover = false;
        this.flatTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(125, 81);
        this.flatTextBox1.MaxLength = 32767;
        this.flatTextBox1.Multiline = false;
        this.flatTextBox1.Name = "flatTextBox1";
        this.flatTextBox1.ReadOnly = false;
        this.flatTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(109, 29);
        this.flatTextBox1.TabIndex = 8;
        this.flatTextBox1.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        this.flatTextBox1.TextColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(192)))), ((int)(((byte)(192)))), ((int)(((byte)(192)))));
        this.flatTextBox1.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
        // 
        // flatLabel1
        // 
        this.flatLabel1.AutoSize = true;
        this.flatLabel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.flatLabel1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 15.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.flatLabel1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.flatLabel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 81);
        this.flatLabel1.Name = "flatLabel1";
        this.flatLabel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(106, 30);
        this.flatLabel1.TabIndex = 7;
        this.flatLabel1.Text = "Username";
        // 
        // flatMini1
        // 
        this.flatMini1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.flatMini1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.flatMini1.BaseColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(45)))), ((int)(((byte)(47)))), ((int)(((byte)(49)))));
        this.flatMini1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Marlett", 12F);
        this.flatMini1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(189, -1);
        this.flatMini1.Name = "flatMini1";
        this.flatMini1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(18, 18);
        this.flatMini1.TabIndex = 6;
        this.flatMini1.Text = "flatMini1";
        this.flatMini1.TextColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(243)))), ((int)(((byte)(243)))), ((int)(((byte)(243)))));
        // 
        // flatMax1
        // 
        this.flatMax1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.flatMax1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.flatMax1.BaseColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(45)))), ((int)(((byte)(47)))), ((int)(((byte)(49)))));
        this.flatMax1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Marlett", 12F);
        this.flatMax1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(213, -1);
        this.flatMax1.Name = "flatMax1";
        this.flatMax1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(18, 18);
        this.flatMax1.TabIndex = 5;
        this.flatMax1.Text = "flatMax1";
        this.flatMax1.TextColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(243)))), ((int)(((byte)(243)))), ((int)(((byte)(243)))));
        // 
        // flatClose1
        // 
        this.flatClose1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.flatClose1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.flatClose1.BaseColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(168)))), ((int)(((byte)(35)))), ((int)(((byte)(35)))));
        this.flatClose1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Marlett", 10F);
        this.flatClose1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(237, 0);
        this.flatClose1.Name = "flatClose1";
        this.flatClose1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(18, 18);
        this.flatClose1.TabIndex = 4;
        this.flatClose1.Text = "flatClose1";
        this.flatClose1.TextColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(243)))), ((int)(((byte)(243)))), ((int)(((byte)(243)))));
        // 
        // flatButton1
        // 
        this.flatButton1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.flatButton1.BaseColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(52)))), ((int)(((byte)(152)))), ((int)(((byte)(219)))));
        this.flatButton1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
        this.flatButton1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 12F);
        this.flatButton1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(74, 209);
        this.flatButton1.Name = "flatButton1";
        this.flatButton1.Rounded = false;
        this.flatButton1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(106, 32);
        this.flatButton1.TabIndex = 11;
        this.flatButton1.Text = "Login";
        this.flatButton1.TextColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(243)))), ((int)(((byte)(243)))), ((int)(((byte)(243)))));
        // 
        // WelcomePage
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(256, 349);
        this.Controls.Add(this.formSkin1);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Name = "WelcomePage";
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.Fuchsia;
        this.formSkin1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.formSkin1.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private FlatUI.FormSkin formSkin1;
    private FlatUI.FlatMini flatMini1;
    private FlatUI.FlatMax flatMax1;
    private FlatUI.FlatClose flatClose1;
    private FlatUI.FlatTextBox flatTextBox2;
    private FlatUI.FlatLabel flatLabel2;
    private FlatUI.FlatTextBox flatTextBox1;
    private FlatUI.FlatLabel flatLabel1;
    private FlatUI.FlatButton flatButton1;
}
```

}

---

PROBLEM HAS BEEN SOLVED! The code for the click detection was missing!

Comment: place a breakpoint on your button click event in the code, and make sure if it really gets executed or not. If not, then you may need to put your form designer code here.

Comment: It's not executing. Let me hunt up the form designer code.

Comment: Added form designer code.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `flatTextBox2.Text` instead of `flatTextBox2` ?

Comment: Alert `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login WHERE Username='" + flatTextBox1.Text + "' AND Password='" + flatTextBox2 + "'", connection)` sql injection detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any event handler attached to the designer code of the button there should be:

```
this.flatButton1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.flatButton1_Click);
```

You have to define a event handler and put the code inside it

```
    private void flatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Your code here
    }
```

Comment: I just didn't show the private void part in the code, it's very much present.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting breakpoint in if/else blocks?

And here is some considerations:
Use prepared statements and parameterized queries. Never ever create dynamic SQL based on user input, because the application becomes vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Here is you rewritten code using parametrized parameters:

```
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@Password", connection);
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", flatTextBox1.Text);
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", flatTextBox2.Text);
```